# Fetch Email Signature Using IMAP Node module

Tags: node.js, imap

I am using IMAP Node module to fetch emails.I am not getting email signature with emails.
Please suggest me,How to get email signature using IMAP Nodejs module.

Comment: Signatures are normally just a chunk of text at the end of the body.  What do you mean you're not getting it?  Do you see it in an IMAP email client?  What do you get? What code are you using to fetch it?

Comment: I am getting dkim-signature in IMAP email.I want to fetch email signature.I just want to know which is part of it is email signature as image?                                                                                           
I am using imap.openBox(mailBox, true, function(err, box) { }  to get mails

Comment: Please provide your working minimal example ( [mre] ), and examples of your output.

Comment: _that.imap.openBox(mailBox, true, function(err, box) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                var f = _that.imap.seq.fetch(mailId, { bodies: '', struct: true });
                var messages = [];
       })

Comment: Please read the linked information on what a [mre] is, and put your information in the question.  Code in comments is very difficult to read.